# how to use data from one Thread in another

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to dynamically add records to `DataGrid` (which I take from mails, running in the background). The problem is that when I use the method on the other thread to start the XAML window, it just prints some records not every one and not dynamically

What I tried:

> Shorten the code to just this

```
AlertTable.ItemsSource = Alert.alerts;
```

but it throws this exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ItemsControl object is not
> consistent with the source of its items.

I also tried adding a new train to contructor, I got this exception

```
Task.Run(() => AddItems());
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access
> this object because it is owned by another thread.'

> AdminWindow.xaml.cs class

```java
public AdminWindow() {
   InitializeComponent();
   foreach (Alert alert in Alert.alerts) {
      alertToDataGrid.Add(alert);
   }
   AlertTable.ItemsSource = Alert.alerts;
}
```

> Contructor for Login(and first window, if users exist, it will create new one - AdminWindow and this will be hide)

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EmailParser parser = new EmailParser(true, "test@mail.cz", "password");
    //Could be problem with Name of the class? I had to rename it, but how I see, it didn't change it properly. But the window is showing...
        }
```

> Method from MailParser class that is running at background for
> receiving mails

public void MailKitLib(EmailParser emailParser)
{

```
            bool help = true;
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.Interval = 500;
            do
            {

                using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                using (var cancel = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource())
                {
                    client.Connect(emailParser.ServerName, emailParser.Port, emailParser.isSSLuse,
                        cancel.Token);

                    //client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH");

                    client.Authenticate(emailParser.Username, emailParser.Password, cancel.Token);


                    var inbox = client.Inbox;
                    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);

                    Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Unread);



                    for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine("ID:" + message.MessageId);
                       
                        if (message.MessageId != null)
                        {
                            Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), "PING" , "LOW");                             
                            Alert.alerts.Add(alert);

                        }


                    }
                   

                    client.Disconnect(true, cancel.Token);
                }
            }
                if (t.Interval == 0)
                {
                    help = false;
                }
            } while (help != false);

        }
```

> EmailParser contructor

```java
public EmailParser(bool isSSLuse, string username, string password) {
   this.ServerName = "imap.outlook.com";
   this.Port = 993;
   this.IsSSLuse = isSSLuse;
   this.Username = username;
   this.Password = password;
   Task.Run(() => MailKitLib(this));
}
```

Comment: This looks confusing. However, you need to add items to the source collection, i.e. the collection that is assigned to the ItemsSource property. In order to automatically update the UI, this should be an ObservableCollection (or any other collection that implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface). You should get rid of the HashSet, and use only an OnservableCollection as source.

Comment: I have edited already

Comment: When you update the source collection from a thread other than the UI thread, you either need to call `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`  first, or use the UI thread's `Dispatcher`.

Comment: @Clemens I am so sorry, but I  still don't understand...

Comment: What exactly I am doing wrong? I thought, that HashSet and easy for avoiding duplicates in array.

Comment: Sure, but it does not notify about changes. It is not the right thing to use here. Maybe take a look at [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73066611/1136211) for an example how to update a source collection from a background thread. Then add some logic that avoids duplicate entries yourself, it is simple.

Comment: So I should create my own class? And what is readonly object? What is his purpose in this case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You would simply use an ObservableCollection instead of a HashSet. Before adding an element, check if the collection already contains an "equal" element. Either replace or remove/add the "equal" element.

Comment: No, I know how to find duplicate. I was talking about your exampl question

Comment: The readonly object there is needed for the collection synchronization. Please take a look at the documentation of EnableCollectionSynchronization.

Comment: `foreach (Alert alert in Alert.alerts) {
      alertToDataGrid.Add(alert);
   }
   AlertTable.ItemsSource = Alert.alerts;
` Is this also wrong?

Comment: Sure, that's useless, because it still uses the HashSet, and `alertToDataGrid` is not used at all. It really makes no sense.

Comment: Can you at least show me a little about my problem, how to proceed,please? So I can get a grip. Especially with the part where I update the source

Comment: I still mainly don't know how to update programmatically `ObservableCollectio`

Comment: By adding, removing or replacing elements. Take a look at the many examples here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I need to change DataGrid, when Application is already running. Is it just removing and adding elements?

Comment: Yes, of course.